# Encabezado circular con map en c++

Tags: c++, map

Estoy haciendo una práctica para la universidad, en esta práctica tenemos *palabras* y *diccionarios de palabras*, entonces los diccionarios contienen palabras y las palabras punteros que nos señalan cuales son sus diccionarios. Aquí es donde aparecen los includes circulares.

Ahora esto lo he solucionado con varias respuestas de este mismo foro añadiendo un class de cada clase en la otra. ¿Qué problema me surge?, Al crear el atributo de tipo map me empiezan a salir errores y no se porque ocurren.

Clase diccionario:

```
#ifndef DICCIONARIOCONVERBOS_H
#define DICCIONARIOCONVERBOS_H
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Palabra;
class DiccionarioConVerbos {
public:
    DiccionarioConVerbos();
    DiccionarioConVerbos(const DiccionarioConVerbos& orig);
    virtual ~DiccionarioConVerbos();
private:
    string nombreDicc="";
    string DiccVerbos="";
    map<std::string, Palabra> Palabras;
};

#endif /* DICCIONARIOCONVERBOS_H */
```

Clase Palabra:

```
#ifndef PALABRA_H
#define PALABRA_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class DiccionarioConVerbos;
class Palabra {
public:  
    .....
    }
private:
    std::string palabra="";
    Documento *doc=nullptr;
    DiccionarioConVerbos *dicc=nullptr;
    int ocurrencias = 0;

};


    
#endif /* PALABRA_H */
```

Salida:

> ```
> cd 'C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VectorDinamico'
> C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean
> "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=
> SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf make.exe[1]: Entering directory
> `/c/Users/Adrian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VectorDinamico' rm -f -r
> build/Debug make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
> `/c/Users/Adrian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VectorDinamico'
>
> CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s) cd
> 'C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VectorDinamico'
> C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
> "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=
> SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf make.exe[1]: Entering directory
> `/c/Users/Adrian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VectorDinamico'
> "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
> dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/vectordinamico.exe make.exe[2]: Entering
> directory `/c/Users/Adrian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VectorDinamico'
> mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows rm -f
> "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/DiccionarioConVerbos.o.d" g++    -c -g
> -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/DiccionarioConVerbos.o.d" -o
> build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/DiccionarioConVerbos.o
> DiccionarioConVerbos.cpp In file included from
> c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:64,
>                  from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h:63,
>                  from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\map:60,
>                  from DiccionarioConVerbos.h:16,
>                  from DiccionarioConVerbos.cpp:14: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h: In
> instantiation of 'struct std::pair<const
> std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Palabra>':
> c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ext\aligned_buffer.h:56:65:
> required from 'struct __gnu_cxx::__aligned_membuf<std::pair<const
> std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Palabra> >'
> c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h:231:41:  
> required from 'struct std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const
> std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Palabra> >'
> c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h:1913:21:  
> required from 'void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare,
> _Alloc>::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Palabra>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Palabra> >; _Compare =
> std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc =
> std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>,
> Palabra> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare,
> _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Palabra> >*]'
> c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h:995:9:  
> required from 'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare,
> _Alloc>::~_Rb_tree() [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Palabra>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Palabra> >; _Compare =
> std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc =
> std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>,
> Palabra> >]'
> c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_map.h:183:7:  
> required from here
> c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h:215:11:
> error: 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second' has incomplete type   215 |      
> _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
>       |           ^~~~~~ In file included from DiccionarioConVerbos.cpp:14: DiccionarioConVerbos.h:20:7: note:
> forward declaration of 'class Palabra'    20 | class Palabra;
>       |       ^~~~~~~ make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/DiccionarioConVerbos.o] Error 1
> make.exe[2]: Leaving directory
> `/c/Users/Adrian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VectorDinamico'
> make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2 make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
> `/c/Users/Adrian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VectorDinamico' make.exe":
> *** [.build-impl] Error 2
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
> ```

Comment: por el código que has pegado, no está separada la declaración de la implementación: no se considera una buena práctica, además que te va a plantear el problema de que si palabra referencia a diccionario y diccionario a Palabra no vas a poder hacerlo: en algún punto te dará que; o bien se ha duplicado una de las dos clases o bien falta por definir una de ellas

Comment: entonces que puedo hacer?

Comment: @AdrianAmaro deberías de tener todas tus declaraciones como por ejemplo  `class Palabra` en un archivo de tipo encabezado que  luego incluyes en tu código. Y luego utilizar archivos de tipo `.cpp` para hacer las definiciones, o inlcusive al final del mismo main si tu código no es tan grande. Estás mezclando definiciones y declaraciones de tus clases y creo que eso es lo que está dándole problemas al compilador y por eso te tira errores como: `forward declaration of 'class Palabra'    20 | class Palabra;`

Answer (score 0):

En el fichero "diccionarioconverbos.h", donde dice:

```
class Palabra;
```

en realidad debe decir:

```
#include "palabra.h"
```

Y lo mismo con el fichero palabra.h. Ahora no se producirán conflictos, porque en el fichero sólo están las declaraciones, no el código.

Comment: no me ha funcionado, me sale error.

Comment: así poco te podemos ayudar. qué error sale?